# How to POST the HTML CODE as a parameter from one page to other

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, cloudpage

I am trying POST two values from a simple HTML form and access it in a CLOUD PAGE using SSJS as below.

My Simple HTML form
[image]
My CLOUD PAGE

```js
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");

var param1 = Platform.Request.GetFormField('CB_Name');
Write(param1); //works correctly

var param2 = Platform.Request.GetFormField('CB_HTML');
Write(param2); //500 - Internal Server Error
</script>
```

**Why the same code works for a simple string, but NOT for HTML CODE!**

- Is this something to do with limitation on number of characters?
- OR should have to encrypt/decrypt/covert to any other format? IF yes, how?

Comment: I believe this in on purpose to prevent HTML Injection attacks. You would have to first encode the HTML and then decode it, I tested this using https://www.web2generators.com/html-based-tools/online-html-entities-encoder-and-decoder and worked fine. So in your scenario, you would have to add encoding and decoding, which can be achieved using RegEx or jQuery.

Comment: @zuzannamj thanks for letting me know on the purpose :) ... also guiding me on the technique to be used... also the above resource was helpful to encode and decode manually! ... but how do I do it PROGRAMATICALLY! ... while doing R n D, I came up with SSJS function `Base64encode` and `Base64decode` will this help to achieve my requirement.

Comment: Vishal, `Base64decode` is a completely different thing. There are no built-in functions for encoding/decoding HTML - you would have to build that function yourself in javascript using either RegEx or jQuery

Comment: @zuzannamj sure... I will give a try and post the code If I am successful.

Comment: @zuzannamj I did a lot of RnD and tried this appoach.... https://coderwall.com/p/jt7ysq/encode-string-to-html-entities-via-jquery ... however though I was able to encode and send the values, I was NOT able to receive in my CLOUD page... it still throws 500 error :( .... any useful resource link would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SFMC's landing pages won't let you post XML or HTML to them. You'll need to encode your CB_HTML field data before posting using JavaScript's btoa() function from client side script and then use Platform.Function.Base64Decode() in your Server Side JavaScript.

There are a number of ways to do this on the client side, but here's a very simple example:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form id="myform" method="POST" action="https://en636wy1jgfih.x.pipedream.net">
            CB Name:<br>
            <input type="text" id="CB_NAME" name="CB_NAME" value="foo">
            <br>
            CB HTML:<br>
            <textarea id="CB_HTML" name="CB_HTML" rows="15">bar</textarea>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            <p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent.</p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById('myform').onsubmit = function() {
    document.getElementById('CB_HTML').value = btoa(document.getElementById('CB_HTML').value);
}
```

**Server Side JavaScript**

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core","1");

    var param1 = Platform.Request.GetFormField('CB_Name');
    Write(param1); //works correctly

    var param2 = Platform.Function.Base64Decode(Platform.Request.GetFormField('CB_HTML'));
    Write(param2); //should also work correctly
</script>
```

Comment: I will use the above technique and confirm, if this worked!

Comment: @ Macca, Thank you so much! `window.btoa()` and `Platform.Function.Base64Decode()` are the functions I was looking for and did the Magic ⛤⛧⛥